# Creating a new list with elements taken out

Tags: python

So what I'm trying to pull off in my python program is to enter any DNA sequence with bases mixed with other extraneous characters, and have an output of a strand with only the bases, in caps. This is the code I've been working on thus far - I am new with python, so I'm not sure why this program isn't working. If you could give me some pointers on what I should add here to make this code work, that would be great.

```
class dnaString (str):
    def __new__(self,s):
        return str.__new__(self,s.upper())
    def bases (list):
        bases = [A,C,T,G]

    def NewStrand (self):
        NewStrand = [self]
        NewStrand = [x for x in NewStrand if x is not A]
        NewStrand = [x for x in NewStrand if x is not C]
        NewStrand = [x for x in NewStrand if x is not T]
        NewStrand = [x for x in NewStrand if x is not G]
        return (NewStrand)

    def printNewStrand (self):
        print ("New DNA strand: {0}".format(self.NewStrand()))

dna = input("Enter a dna sequence: ")
x=dnaString(dna)
x.NewStrand()
```

Comment: What's the expected input and output?

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to do what you are trying to do, using classes is kind of an overkill.

This is all you need:

```
bases = 'ATGC'
strand = raw_input("Enter a dna sequence: ")
output = filter(lambda x: x.lower() in bases.lower(), strand)
output = output.upper()
print output
```

It uses python's [`filter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#filter) function to filter out unwanted characters.

- We first declare the allowed characters in `bases`.
- `crap` can be any user input accepted from the `raw_input()` function.
- `output` makes a call to the function `filter` which accepts an iterable and filters elements out of it based on a function that is passed as the second parameter to the `filter()` function.
- [`lambda`](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#lambda-expressions) is a construct in python that lets you define small anonymous functions.

**EDIT:**

Looks like you are using python 3. raw_input is not defined in python 3 and the way filter returns values in python 3 is different. So for python 3 you would do this:

```
bases = 'ATGC'
strand = input("Enter a dna sequence: ")
output = list(filter(lambda x: x.lower() in bases.lower(), strand))
output = ''.join(output)
output = output.upper()
print(output)
```

Comment: oh, ok. But see, that takes care of a specific strand. I want to be able to enter any DNA strand

Comment: @user3504701 No, instead of `'aksjdkjahsdtgwefschkjAKJHTKJHKGCKJ'` you can ask the user to input any strand. Updated my answer to reflect that.

Comment: is that all I really have to add? the program still doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Do you see errors? What are the input and expected output?

Comment: the input is "enter DNA sequence", which is fine. But instead of the output, the error reads: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "...", line 4, in <module>
    output = output.upper()
AttributeError: 'filter' object has no attribute 'upper'

Comment: I changed the input() to raw_input(). Can you check now?

Comment: that just gives this error message:Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "...", line 2, in <module>
    strand = raw_input("Enter a dna sequence: ")
NameError: name 'raw_input' is not defined

Comment: @user3504701 You are using python 3 while I was trying things on python 2.7 :) Have updated my answer with code for python 3

Answer (score 0):

A single function is all you need. This one uses a generator expression instead of `filter` and `lambda` but the result is the same.

```
>>> def strand(base="ACTG"):
...     """ Return a strand from user input """
...     s = raw_input("Enter a sequence: ")
...     return "".join(x for x in s.lower() if x in base.lower()).upper()
...

>>> strand()
Enter a sequence: asdffeeakttycasdgeadc
'AATTCAGAC'
```

Another example:

```
>>> strand()
Enter a sequence: asdfsdf29038520395slkdgjw3l4ktjnd,cvmbncv,bhieruoykrjghcxvb
'AGTCCGC
```